# Trying Post CSV to Rapidminer WebServices

Tags: javascript, firebase, csv, post, rapidminer

I'm stuck with a JS code since a few days, to send a CSV to my Rapidminer Webservice and get back the answer with the results.

I have the code hosted in a Firebase function to POST CSV to my WebService URL:

[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMlnO.png)

For the web service I use a Read CSV to read the file that the user passes me in the POST.

The web service is configured to receive a UTF-8 text/xml
and published in /api/rest/public/anonymous as a route to not need authentication.

I tried to invoke it from cmd with Curl by upload-files and it correctly returned the result in XML format.

So when I make the call with JS from my firebase I try to send a CSV but always without response from the server.
[rapidminer webservice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtvES.png)

Error Firebase timeout function:
[firebase error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVrhU.png)

UPDATE:

The code is working locally but not on firebase server.

ERROR:
[ERROR FIREBASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJn5q.png)

Comment: I've tried to send with form-data as well.

Comment: Hello tobeal, welcome to SO! To get great answers on your posts you need to be as elaborate as possible. Asking a good question is not an easy task and it requires effort - from all of us at SO. Please take a few minutes to go through the documents in the help center, for example: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then add more information to your question. What have you tried so far in your past few days? What exactly are you expecting to be the result?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I tried to send JSON to a web service that received it and processed it through the Rapidminer recommendation system and returned a series of recommendations, however this was not possible.
Now I am sending a CSV that processes the service and gives me an answer of the recommendations according to my sent data.
I have tried to send this CSV with :
-Express
-XMLHttpRequest
-Axios
-Ajax

However, I have not been able to run the service as I always get errors.

Among these errors are:  TypeError: "string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer on send

Comment: Then please update all this information to your question, add as much detail as you can. Add your code (instead of an image), format your question, etc. You will get a great answer a lot quicker if you put effort to the question.

Comment: okey, thank you soo much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a macro binding for the webservice and pass the information as a simple GET parameter (url?csv=foo,bar), then just use the "Create ExampleSet" operator with the generator type "comma separated text" and the %{csv} macro as "input csv text".

That's probably not the most elegant way, but should at least work for your usecase.

Comment: it´s working on node, but when i am trying put it on firebase function, it doesn´t work. Console log shows me the same csv on the two platform (firebase and node command line) but the error of the timeout´s function appear in firebase when i run the function

Comment: You'll need to be on a paid plan to make external API requests in firebase.